# how can I find the related image version with the kubernetes version?

Tags: kubernetes

When I use `kubeadm` to install Kubernetes, I can use the command below to get.

```
kubeadm config images list
```

the output like:

```
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.12.2
k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.12.2
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.12.2
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.12.2
k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1
k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.2.24
k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.2.2
```

Besides `kubeadm`, how can I find the related image version with the kubernetes version?

Answer (score 1):

As per [List All Container Images Running in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/#list-containers-filtering-by-pod-namespace), you can use:

`kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system -o jsonpath="{..image}"`

This will list all images used by containers running in `kube-system` namespace.

You can use `go-template` to improve the formatting. Here is an output example using a vanilla Minikube:

```
$ kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -o go-template --template='{{range .items}}{{range .spec.containers}}{{.image}}{{"\n"}} {{end}}{{end}}'
 k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.2
 k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.2
 k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.3.15-0
 k8s.gcr.io/kube-addon-manager:v9.0.2
 k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.16.0
 k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.16.0
 k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.16.0
 k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.16.0
 gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v1.8.1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer，this method can get the version, but I think this method is based on running Kubernetes. can I get the container image version before installing the Kubernetes?